# My action controller code looks amateurish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actioncontroller

First post time,

I've been playing around with MVC abit... I have a view which has multiple input fields, some of these fields can be blank on post.

The action method inside the controller for the post looks something like this

```
public ActionResult Filter(int? id, string firstName, string lastName, bool? isMember)
```

I've been using the DynamicQuery extension which has been kicking around in order to perform dynamic Linq querys on my database and I've encapsulated this in a Search object which is passed to the data access layer for execusion.

However, I also have a customized ViewData object which is passed back to the view for displaying the input values and the results of the query.

It all looks a little nasty in code as I'm having to set both the Search object properties AND the ViewDatas.

```
public ActionResult Filter(int? id, string firstName, string lastName, bool? isMember)  { 
var search = new Search { 
Id = id, 
FirstName = firstName, 
LastName = lastName, 
Member =  isMember 
}; 

var memberViewData = new MemberViewData { 
Id = id, 
FirstName = firstName, 
LastName = lastName, 
Member =  isMember
}; 

memberViewData.Results = _dataRepository.GetMember(search); 

return View("Search", memberViewData); 

}
```

Am I over thinking this and really should just pass the values to the data access layer and populate the ViewData in the controller, or is there a much more elegant pattern or practise I could use?

Sorry if this seems dump, not allot of people to bounce ideas off and time to dig into the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your snippet MemberViewData class has the Results property in addition to properties of Search class. So first step would be to make MemberViewData derive from Search and define a constructor that accepts Search instance as parameter and assigns it's basic properties from it. Next I would change the action method like so:

```
public ActionResult Filter(Search search)  
{ 
    return View("Search", new MemberViewData(search) 
    {
        Results = _dataRepository.GetMember(search)
    }); 
}
```

Comment: intresting, but as I understand it I can only pass input fields from the view to the ActionMethod, where is Search instantiated?

Comment: Just managed to find some time to play with this and I can see that Mvc will try to bind the form fields to the properties on the object by default without any extra coding !!

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It uses a default model binder that you could override if you needed some more fine grained control over parameter binding.

Answer (score 2):

Use modelbinder to bind data

Answer (score 0):

Like Tadeusz mentioned, a ModelBinder can help build the MemberViewData for you, which would leave only the results to be fetched.

You could also decide on creating a presentation service that understands how to build this view data object and simply delegate to it.  I'd prefer the model binder approach here though.